# She was to have married

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

> She died quickly, shortly before **she was to have married**.

In the above sentence, what does it mean by "she was to have married"?

Does it mean "she was to get married"?

Answer (score 1):

> She died quickly, shortly before she was to have married.
>
> She died quickly, shorty before she was to get married.
>
> She died quickly, shortly before she was to be married.

are all very nearly meaning-identical.

All have exactly the same time indications, although the time indicator p.p. in the first has a different tense:  there was a planned wedding, and she died sometime between the time the date was set and the wedding itself.

The first is slightly less common use, and may sound a little antiquated to some listeners.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer ！